# Hyperledger Fabric error: "TLS: bad certificate server" when installing chaincode

Tags: ssl, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm just starting learning HLF, and I have an error while following tutorial from the docs: [link](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/release-2.2/deploy_chaincode.html)

I downloaded fabric-samples using this command (replaced bit.ly link with the destination):

```
curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s -- 2.2.2 1.4.9
```

I run logspout in one terminal and try to execute `peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz` in another one, and this is the result i get

> Error: failed to retrieve endorser client for install: endorser client
> failed to connect to localhost:7051: failed to create new connection:
> context deadline exceeded

Log presented by Logspout:

> peer0.org1.example.com|2022-03-15 13:03:24.452 UTC [core.comm]
> ServerHandshake -> ERRO 04a Server TLS handshake failed in 2.650245ms
> with error remote error: tls: bad certificate server=PeerServer
> remoteaddress=172.22.0.1:61126

I set the envs in terminal as instructed in the docs, and I checked that `CORE_PEER_TLS_ROOTCERT_FILE` variable points to an existing file. The content of the file is the same as on the container.

What I tried to do:

- download fabric-samples again and redo all the setup with copy-pasting the commands directly from docs

Do you have any suggestions where I can look for an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem, I was using peer version 2.2.1 from previous experiments, it probably collided with FABRIC_CFG_PATH